# HTTP Post message with bad request No direct Error message

Tags: javascript, c#, api

Hi i get an error when doing a post message.
I have changed naming to url and object.
The url works(when i open it in the browser i cannect to it without a problem (get message)
When i do an post message i get following answer:
400 (Bad Request)
i do not see a mistake.
Another post message with a diffrent url and obejct works great

I have just copied paste the code.

But i can see no error ore a error messsage that can help me here

JS Code

`````
 let nxObjects = [];
nxObjects.push({

                name: "test"
               
            });

let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('POST', 'URL');
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(nxObjects));````




C# API

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using namespace;

namespace namespace 
{
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NXController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet()]
        public IEnumerable<Order> Select() => NXobject.GetList();

    

        [HttpPost()]
        public IActionResult Update([FromBody] NX NXobject)
        {
            ObjectResult result = null;
            try
            {
                NXobject.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is my Log" + ex);
            }

            return result;
        }
```
`````

Comment: You should check your attribute in object NX. This problem is occured because your request cant be correct parse.

Comment: I cannot even debug.Somwhere between sending the request and reveiving it is something lost. If there would be something wrong with the property i am sure i would not even can make a HTTP get. This just happens while HTTP Post

Comment: bad request mean the url path is correct but there's something (header or body format) is incorrect. you can't use api debug in this case, just make sure the client make the proper request to the api.

Comment: Try without `[FromBody]` . It is basically used for multipart data. Try `update(NX nxobjects)`